# STL or ranges algorithm to efficiently find n consecutive elements that satisfy predicate

Tags: c++, stl, c++20, range-v3

I have the following function(toy example, but good for demonstration):

```
  // finds the iterator pointing to the start of n consectuve 47s or return values.end() if not found
  auto find_n_47s(const int n, const std::vector<int>& values){
    std::vector<bool> predicate_result;
    predicate_result.reserve(values.size());
    std::transform(values.begin(), values.end(), std::back_inserter(predicate_result), []
                   (const auto& val){return val==47; });
    std::vector<bool> search_pattern(n, true);
    auto it= std::search(predicate_result.begin(), predicate_result.end(), 
                       search_pattern.begin(), search_pattern.end());
    return values.begin() + std::distance(predicate_result.begin(), it);  
}
```

I am looking for a nicer and more efficient way to accomplish the same thing.

My problems:

1. I can not use manual iteration + std::all_of(from current element to
   n elements ahead) because it is too slow(in theory for every element
   that I do up to n predicate applications).
2. My solution allocates memory and calculates predicate for every
   element although we might find the result in the first 1% of the
   elements.

Full code here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/rBVFS64IcOI6gKe6

Comment: "*in theory for every element that I do up to n predicate applications*" How else could you possibly know when you have the result? What you want *has to be* O(n) in terms of the number of invocations of the predicate. It's no different from asking for a sort algorithm that is less than O(n); it's logically impossible, because you have to do at least n compares just to know that the sequence is sorted.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search_n

Comment: @NicolBolas n is the not the size of the vector, but the length of subsequence

Comment: @CruzJean - it does not work for custom unary predicate

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl A binary predicate is a superset of unary predicates in this case: just pass some value to it to search for and have your binary predicate take that type as second arg but only base logic on the first arg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Cruz Jean pointed out you can use search_n:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/ENgEi5ZVPDx1D1GQ

The GCC implementation of search_n

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h

does not check every element:

```
|---------|---------|---------|----------------|
|  Find first occurence of n=7 consecutive 47  |
|---------|---------|---------|----------------|
|  vector |  step#  |  count  |                |
|---------|---------|---------|----------------|
|  47     |         |         |                |
|  47     |         |         |                |
|  47     |         |         |                |
|  0      |  4      |  3      |                |
|  47     |  3      |  3      |                |
|  47     |  2      |  2      |                |
|  47     |  1      |  1      |  start         |
|  47     |         |         |                |
|  47     |         |         |                |
|  0      |  5      |  0      |                |
|  47     |         |         |                |
|  0      |         |         |                |
|  0      |         |         |                |
|  47     |         |         |                |
|  0      |         |         |                |
|  47     |         |         |                |
|  0      |  6      |  0      |                |
|  0      |         |         |                |
|  0      |         |         |                |
|  0      |         |         |                |
|  0      |         |         |                |
|  47     |         |         |                |
|  0      |         |         |                |
|  0      |  7      |  0      |                |
|  47     |         |         |                |
|  47     |         |         |                |
|  47     |         |         |                |
|  47     |         |         |                |
|  0      |         |         |                |
|  0      |  9      |  1      |                |
|  47     |  8      |  1      |                |
|  47     |  15     |  7      |  success       |
|  47     |  14     |  6      |                |
|  47     |  13     |  5      |                |
|  47     |  12     |  4      |                |
|  47     |  11     |  3      |                |
|  47     |  10     |  2      |                |
|  47     |         |         |                |
|  0      |         |         |                |
|  0      |         |         |                |
|  47     |         |         |                |
|  0      |         |         |                |
|  …      |         |         |                |
|---------|---------|---------|----------------|
```

Comment: Just watched Conor Hoekstra's great talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEvYmb3eKsw about agorithm intuition  but @ 37:30 I would prefer a std::search_n solution: https://godbolt.org/z/AO8HtG